# How do I find C & L from XC and XL?

Tags: capacitor, inductor, capacitive, inductive, reactance

**Calculating Capacitance and Inductance from Capacitive Reactance and Inductive Reactance**

I'm trying to find the inductor (L) and capacitor (C) values using the inductive reactance (XL) and capacitive reactance (XC).
Edit: I also have the frequency (f=50 Hz).

I know \$XL = 2\pi f L\$ and I know \$XC = \dfrac{1}{2\pi f C}\$, but I am not the best at reversing formulas, I am still learning.

Can anyone confirm the correct formulas please?

I have tried assigning random values to each part of the equations, but my answers don't seem to match up for some reason. I don't know where I am going wrong, but nevertheless keen to learn and willing to ask.

I have also tried searching online, but the only articles I can find of relevance are about calculating XC and XL, not C and L from XC and XL.

Comment: Do you have the frequency?

Comment: Yes frequency is 50 Hz

Comment: This question might be better suited for a basic algebra site rather than EE.

Comment: Then I afraid you will have to go back to a very basic math books/classes in order to proceed with electrical engineering..

Comment: @ John D Well, I am an EE student, so figured it was relevant if they are teaching it, but I will try find a basic algebra site, thanks.

Comment: @Eugene there's no need to be mean, I've come here for answers because I heard this is where the experts are.

Comment: For the \$X_L\$ equation just divide both sides by \$2\pi f\$ to solve for \$L\$.

Comment: I am not mean, you *really* need it, take it as a friendly advice. You can't do any engineering without knowing how to solve a basic linear equation with a single unknown.

Comment: I'm just the kind of person who needs to know I've got it completely right before proceeding. If you don't ask questions you don't learn.

Comment: Sometimes, we all stand on our own power line. But no kidding, math is getting much much worse from here. But there's hope if you are allowed to use a self-written cheat-sheet in exams.

Comment: @EugeneSh. In the context of the question - which was generall - the actual frequency is irrelevant.

Comment: @EMFields *"I'm trying to find the inductor (L) and capacitor (C) **values**"*. My question was to clarify whether it is a two equations with two unknowns or three.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: The subject of her question was: How do I find C & L from XC and XL?"  Since she stated that she already knew the formulas for getting the values of inductive and capacitive reactances, and also stated: "but I am not the best at reversing formulas," it's apparent - to me, at least - that she was looking for  a way to rearrange the formulas, knowing everything else, which would allow her to  solve for the values of L and C.  That generality made your asking for a specific frequency irrelevant since you didn't also ask for \$X_L\$ or \$X_C\$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Where

- \$f\$ is frequency in hertz
- \$C\$ is capacitance in farads
- \$X_C \$ is capacitive reactance in ohms
- \$L\$ is inductance in henrys, and
- \$X_L\$ is inductive reactance in ohms,

and you start with:

$$ X_L = 2 \ \pi \ f\ L, $$

then divide both sides of the equation by \$2\pi\ f\$ in order to isolate the \$ L\$, you'll get:

$$ \frac {X_L}{2 \ \pi \ f}= \frac{ \require{cancel} \cancel { 2 \ \pi \ f}\ L}{ \require{cancel} \cancel { 2 \ \pi \ f}}\text{ .} $$

Move the \$L\$ over to the left hand side and, like magic, Voila!
$$ L= \frac{X_L}{2 \ \pi \ f}\ $$

Rearranging to get the capacitance, if you start with:

$$Xc = \frac{1}{2 \ \pi \ f\ C}  $$

and multiply both sides of the equation by C, in order to put C in a less cumbersome place to work with, you'll get:

$$C\ X_C = \frac{1\require{cancel} \cancel {C}}{2 \ \pi \ f\require{cancel} \cancel {C}} $$

Finally, in order to isolate C and put the reactive term in its place, divide through by\$ X_C\$ and you'll get:

$$ \frac{C \require{cancel} \cancel {X_C}}{\require{cancel} \cancel {X_C}} = \frac{1}{2\pi\ f\ X_C}{ \text{ , }} $$ and after you clean it all up you'll have:

$$ C  = \frac{1}{2\pi\ f\ X_C}$$